# Counting the checked radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using 4 radiobuttons as options to a question. The question and the radiobuttons are refreshed after button click. The checked radiobutton text is compared  with the answer and if it matches, a counter is increased. I have found that when I check a radiobutton first time the corresponding radiobutton on the next question will be checked already and if it is the answer it will increase the counter and if i change it to check another radiobutton which is the actual answer the counter is not increased. Do I have to specify any property for the updatepanel that i am using to refresh the question. Thnk you for time to read this long one.

This is my aspx code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style>
        .con{
            width:70%;
            margin:auto;
        }
        .testres{
            display:none;
        }
        .btnHome{
            display:none;
            color:rgb(0,159,37);
            text-decoration:none;
            background:none;
            border:1px solid grey;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div class="con">
    <div class="subject-name">
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Subject : " /><asp:Label ID="lblSubjectName" runat="server" Text="" />
    </div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="question-options">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><asp:Label ID="lblQ" runat="server" Text="Q.No. "/><asp:Label ID="lblQuesNo" runat="server" Text="" /></legend>
                    <asp:Panel ID="question" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQues" runat="server" Text="" />
                        <ul style="list-style-type:none">

                            <li><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1"  runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="answer" Text="" /></li>
                            <li><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="answer" Text=""  /></li>
                            <li><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="answer" Text="" /></li>
                            <li><asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" GroupName="answer" Text="" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="testres" runat="server">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Correct Answers : "></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnNext" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnNext_Click"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnHome" runat="server" Text="Home" CssClass="btnHome" OnClick="btnHome_Click"/>
                 </fieldset>
               </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

This is code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class OnlineTest_Question : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Password=password@123;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=MyDatabasae;Data Source=.");
    SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader rdr;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    static int rowcount=0;
    static int totalrowcount;
    string id = "";
    string subname = "";
    string correctans = "";
    int i = 1;
    static int correctcount = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select subject from subjectstb where subid='" + Request.QueryString["sid"] + "'";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                subname = rdr["subject"].ToString();
            }
            rdr.Close();
            con.Close();
            lblSubjectName.Text = subname;
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from questionstb where subject='" + Request.QueryString["sid"] + "'";
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
                totalrowcount = dt.Rows.Count;
                lblQues.Text = dt.Rows[0]["question"].ToString();
                id = dt.Rows[0]["qid"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from optionstb where qid='" + id + "'";
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt1.Load(rdr);
                RadioButton1.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton2.Text = dt1.Rows[1]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton3.Text = dt1.Rows[2]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton4.Text = dt1.Rows[3]["choice"].ToString();
                lblQuesNo.Text = (rowcount + 1).ToString();

                correctans = dt1.Rows[0]["correct"].ToString();


                    if (RadioButton1.Checked == true && RadioButton1.Text == correctans)
                    {
                        correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                    }
                    else if (RadioButton2.Checked == true && RadioButton2.Text == correctans)
                    {
                        correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                    }
                    else if (RadioButton3.Checked == true && RadioButton3.Text == correctans)
                    {
                        correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                    }
                    else if (RadioButton4.Checked == true && RadioButton4.Text == correctans)
                    {
                        correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                    }


            }


            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }



    }

    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if(rowcount<5)
        {
            if(rowcount>=totalrowcount)                                         
            {
            lblQuesNo.Text = "Not Available";
            lblQues.Text = "No more questions available.";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from questionstb where subject='" + Request.QueryString["sid"] + "'";
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt3.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
                totalrowcount = dt3.Rows.Count;
                lblQuesNo.Text = (rowcount+1).ToString();
                lblQues.Text = dt3.Rows[rowcount]["question"].ToString();
                dt1.Load(rdr);

                id = dt3.Rows[rowcount]["qid"].ToString();
                cmd.CommandText = "select * from optionstb where qid='" + id + "'";
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                dt2.Load(rdr);
                rdr.Close();
                RadioButton1.Text = dt2.Rows[0]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton2.Text = dt2.Rows[1]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton3.Text = dt2.Rows[2]["choice"].ToString();
                RadioButton4.Text = dt2.Rows[3]["choice"].ToString();

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from optionstb where qid='"+id+"'";
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable d=new DataTable();
                d.Load(rdr);
                correctans = d.Rows[0]["correct"].ToString();

                if (RadioButton1.Checked == true && RadioButton1.Text == correctans)
                {
                    correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                }
                else if (RadioButton2.Checked == true && RadioButton2.Text == correctans)
                {
                    correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                }
                else if (RadioButton3.Checked == true && RadioButton3.Text == correctans)
                {
                    correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                }
                else if (RadioButton4.Checked == true && RadioButton4.Text == correctans)
                {
                    correctcount = correctcount + 1;
                }

                rowcount = rowcount + 1;

             }

        }
        else
        {
            con.Close();
            Label2.Text = correctcount.ToString();
            question.Style.Add("display","none");
            Panel1.Style.Add("display", "block");
            btnNext.Text = "";
            lblQ.Text = "Result";
            btnHome.Style.Add("display", "block");
            lblQuesNo.Text = "";
            btnNext.Style.Add("background", "none");
            btnNext.Style.Add("border", "none");
        }

    }
    protected void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rowcount = 0;
        correctcount = 0;
        Response.Redirect("testselect.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: We're happy to help, but to know what's going on, we need to see the code you have for your updatepanel and codebehind for the checkbox counting. Otherwise, there's no way of telling what's happening.

Comment: RadioButtons are not difficult to use. I suspect that the "group" is not defined precisely, but without code is very difficult to trace the error

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code chunk that controls this process. Otherwise we can not help you.